# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask for an English translation of a Greek poem?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have an Italian edition of a Greek poem, and I know the same book has been published in some English speaking countries; I would like to ask if anyone has the official translation of it.
Shall I ask the question on the English Language community? It doesn't really look appropriate though. In there a more specific place where can I ask or I should simply give up?

Comment: I doubt that you can find “offical” translations of poems. Only contracts and other official documents tend to be officially translated.

Comment: @Chenmunka Unfortunately it is a love poem by Yiannis Ritsos.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft What I mean is that I could translate it myself from Italian or Greek, but I was interested in the professional and higher-quality translation of the English version of the book.

Comment: http://www.poetryfoundation.org/bio/yannis-ritsos - There are a few English transaltions in the Poems, Articles & More tab.

Comment: @Yannis Thank you, but the Google for once doesn't seem to have an answer. 'The Apples of the Hesperides I' by Ritsos in English is simpy impossible to find. Cheers

Comment: @KillingBambi Ah, you'll find a translation in Keeley's Repetitions, Testimonies, Parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty certain that there is no existing Stack Exchange that would welcome such questions in general. However, if the poem is of specific interest to some community such as [Mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) or [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/), your question may falls into its scope.

Moreover, there is a [Literature proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature?referrer=x5gk8vOgaR9D4yRnMOivZg2), which may result in a site where you can ask such questions.

Comment: Very interesteing. According to your experience, is there a concrete probability that the proposal may eventually result in a site?

Comment: @KillingBambi There was an earlier literature proposal that failed, that's not a good sign. The new proposal is just a day old, however, it's simply too early to tell. Best you can do is follow it, and perhaps suggest a few example questions.

Answer (score 4):

This question is on-topic for the [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) site mentioned in the other answer. We actually have a [meta discussion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/211/) about this exact topic. Typical tags used for a question of this sort:

- [translation](/questions/tagged/translation)
- [x-literature](/questions/tagged/x-literature) (where "x" is the original language of publication, provided it is not English; you would use [greek-literature](/questions/tagged/greek-literature))
- Author/work tags (since you're asking about a poem, per our [short-works policy](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/), the correct work tag would be [poetry](/questions/tagged/poetry))

Here is a [similar question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3668/) as an example.